# 2D rotation matrix: express sin and cos in terms of the elements and the norm of an arbitrary non-zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

2D rotation matrix is used to derive the expressions for sin and cos in terms of
$a_1 ,a_2 and ||\vec{a}|| $ with the following given

[image: Rotation matrix details]

I'm trying to figure out where the negative-sign comes from in the below expression for sin. Any suggestions?

[image: In terms of a1, a2 and norm of a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a coordinate system $(x,y)$ is established. Now establish a new coordinate system $(x',y')$ by rotating the axes counter-clockwise by angle $\theta$.  We must have for any vector

$$\vec r =\hat xx+\hat yy=\vec r' =\hat x'x' +\hat y'y'$$

Taking the inner product of both sides with $\hat x$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\hat x \cdot \vec r&=x\\
&=\hat x \cdot \vec r'\\
&=(\hat x\cdot \hat x')x'+(\hat x\cdot \hat y')y'\\
&=(\cos \theta) \,\,x'+(\cos (\theta+\pi/2)) \,\,y'\\
&=(\cos \theta) \,\,x'-(\sin \theta) \,\,y'
\end{align}$$

Taking the inner product of both sides with $\hat y$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\hat y \cdot \vec r&=y\\
&=\hat y \cdot \vec r'\\
&=(\hat y\cdot \hat x')x'+(\hat y\cdot \hat y')y'\\
&=(\cos (\pi/2-\theta)) \,\,x'+(\cos \theta) \,\,y'\\
&=(\sin \theta) \,\,x'+(\cos \theta) \,\,y'
\end{align}$$

Comment: What exactly does $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ represent? Wondering how you get the 1.st 2 equalities when you take the inner products?

Comment: The notation $\hat x$ denotes a unit vector along the $x$ axis. So, if we take an inner product of a unit vector with itself, then the result is $1$. If we take an inner product of a unit vector with an orthogonal unit vector, then the result is $0$.  In general, if we take the inner product of any two unit vectors, then the result is the cosine of the angle between them.  Helpful?

Comment: I agree to your last comment. However I still can't quite see the magic behind $\vec r =\hat xx+\hat yy$. I'm not used to this notation, so it might be the reason I don't recognize this.
I guess $\vec r$ can be represented as $\vec r^2 = \vec x^2 + \vec y^2 $ from Pythagoras if I understand $\vec r$ correctly.

Comment: So, $\vec r$ is the position vector with components $x$ in the $\hat x$ direction and $y$ in the $\hat y$ direction.  The magnitude of this vector is denoted $|\vec r| =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the square of the magnitude is $|\vec r|^2 =x^2+y^2$.  Note that the square of the magnitude is also given by $|\vec r|^2 =\vec r \cdot \vec r= x^2+y^2$

Comment: The hat over r is the polar analogue to the cartesian system, with i, j and k.
Thx

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. We have, $\vec r=\hat r r$ where in Cartesian coordinates, $\hat r=\hat x \cos \theta +\hat y \sin \theta=\hat x (x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) +\hat y (y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=\vec r/r$